# How to catch error in this promise stack?

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise

I am now trying to write my own Promises.
Then thing is that I don't know how to reject the promise when I stack 3 promises

Here are the codes

```
const onFinish = (values) => {

  const UpdateItem = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Update the item
      resolve(this.props.updateItem(this.props.item.items, index));
    });
  };
  const AddSale = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Add To Sale
      resolve(this.props.addSale(newSale));
      // ;
    });
  };
  const reloadPage = () => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(window.location.reload());
      },1000)
    });
  };

  UpdateItem()
    .then(() => AddSale())
    .then(() => reloadPage())
  }
```

As you can see I am using react-redux.
What I imagining here is that When I hit submit the form

First I will update then item. then add a new sale then reload the page

The problem is that when I hit submit an item is updated but the new sale is not made. But the page is reloaded.

So the new sale not made and the item is decreased.

So how should I change the code so that the page will not reload && the item is not updated when there is an error.

Here is the Actions code

```
export const addSale = (sale) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // will hit reducer
    // console.log(sale)
    Axios.post("/api/sales", sale, tokenConfig(getState))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_SALE,
          // res.data is new sale
          payload: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      });
  };

export const updateItem = (item, index) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // will hit reducer
  // console.log(item[index]);
  // console.log(item);
  // console.log(index)
  Axios.post(
    `/api/items/update/${item[index]._id}`,
    item[index],
    tokenConfig(getState)
  ).then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_ITEM,
      // res.data is new item
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Well, are `this.props.updateItem` and `this.props.addSale` synchronous calls? What is the reason why these are wrapped in a `Promise`?

Comment: Do you really need to reload the page? The user experience would be better if you didn't reload.

Comment: @goto1
I just wanna try the promises. I think the program will less prone to error when i use promises

Comment: @ShadowMitia
The problem is that when i submit the form the page won't reload so 
The input data are still there.

I am using third party library so I choose the easy way and refresh the page

Comment: @Khant As long as it works^^ But you could remove the data after it's submitted too. But one problem at a time^^ On the long run, I would advise against reloading the page all the time.

Comment: you don't need to create new Promises in order to use an existing Promise, you might want to learn a bit more about them, e.g. from [You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance - Chapter 3: Promises](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it drifted from "how to catch an error in promise" to completely different issues/problems. I answered on initial question but I didn't catch updates in it before submitting my answer, so feel free to ignore it if it doesn't solve anything...

Answer (score 1):

1. don't create new Promises to handle `.then()` of an existing Promise

```js
const onFinish = (values) => {
  const updateItem = () => this.props.updateItem(this.props.item.items, index)
  const addSale = () => this.props.addSale(newSale)
  const reloadPage = () => window.location.reload()

  updateItem()
    .then(addSale)
    .then(reloadPage)
}
```

2. `catch()` converts a rejected Promise into a resolved one => re-throw the error inside `catch` if you need a rejected Promise (to stop executing following `then`s)

```js
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
        throw err
      })
```